# Ubuntu volume change in percents

Tags: gnome, sound, gui

Whenever I use combination of `FN+F2/F3` it changes the volume, but only for pre selected value, like it always goes up or down for a fixed amount, so it's not very useful. Is there any way to make this behaviour act like it's in Windows, when you can see the exact percentage of volume out of 100? My version is 20.04 LTS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to display percentages for the default volume UI. However, if you hold Shift then use your F2/F3, it will increase or decrease the volume at a smaller amount with each tick, giving you a bit more control over the volume.

Hope this helps.